# How to save Watson Conversation history in my mySQL database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress, watson-conversation

I just deployed the Watson Conversation plugin on Wordpress and its working very well - I can talk to Watson and he works just as he does in Bluemix.

However, I have no way to then see or manage the conversation history (aside from going into Bluemix).

The WP plugin has the api.php and app.js and I know one of these must at some point handle the text that the user inputs and Watson responds.

Does anyone know how I could save that conversation into my WP mySQL database, so I can analyze and work with it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If this plugin is using Nodejs (because of `app.js`) you need to create one custom code for it. Probably, the `app.js` have the call for the Conversation Service.

If this is your case...

You need to access the Log from Conversation service and get the return, and after it, save inside one MySQL database.

Using the plugin `mysql` inside the app.js if the lib Watson-Developer-Cloud is inside the code. And access the Logs with [getLogs](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/master/conversation/v1.js#L1516) function. Where the `Conversationv1` is the call for this service.

For use the mysql lib, please follow the example code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connMySQL = function(){
            return mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'yourUser',
            password: 'yourPassword',
            database: 'nameDatabase'
        });
}

module.exports = function (){
    return connMySQL;
}
```

I really recommend [this](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/blob/master/app.js) project for you know the follow steps. In this case, the call for conversation service is the `conversation` variable, and for access the return, like `entities`, `context` varibles, etc, you will use the `data` [return](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/blob/master/app.js#L60).

For example:

```
data.context.contextVariableInsideWatson
```

Official reference from IBM Developers: [watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/)
Repository with one simple project using Conversation from IBM Developers [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/).